# How to add image URL in Google Sheet through Google appsheet

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-appsheet

I want to add image URL in Googlesheet if the image is uploaded through google appsheet. And I want to store this pic in g-drive in folder.

I tried to make changes in appsheet and make a bot in appsheet but I didn't get image URL.

Comment: We are not a code writing service.  If you have specific questions about  the code feel free to ask them, otherwise plan to develop most of the code on your own.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can see the code that you are using to create the problem.  Please post it into you question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.